# No fluid simulation anymore

Tags: modeling

I needed to free up my data to re-bake it, and now my domain is stuck at the solid square box even after baking data and mesh. If someone can help me out, that would be amazing. I have attached the blender file through the dropbox link. Thank you so much. I even put it in bounds viewport to see if I could see the particles, and nothing.

Blender file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2t7o0jjr3z9oev/can%20blend.blend%20fix%20copy%20.blend?dl=0

Comment: you obviously deleted your fluid. You just have a domain and effectors in your scene, but no fluid of type liquid at all.

Comment: @Chris hey Chris thank you lol, it wasn’t obvious at 7 this morning, so not sure where my fluid went I just rendered them. but thank you so much!! :)